# How to insert and update the inserted row in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I want my "Create" button to insert a row on a table and once inserted to update that row. The reason I need to insert that row first and then update is because some columns that I want to update depend on the value being there in the first place. For example I would like to update the "Gross Margin" column but the "Gross Margin" = Payrate + something else. If I don't have the value in "Payrate" column, well there is no way I can update "Gross Margin" since it depends on it.

What I have tried:

1. ) Create a Dynamic Action that triggers if "create" button is clicked. If its clicked is true then run the 2 true actions of type "Execute server side code" which is the Insert statement and the other is the Update statement. I made sure that Insert has the first sequence(It runs first) then the update(It runs second). Please see below picture of the settings of the "Create" button.

[image]

Please see below picture of the settings of the "Dynamic action"

[image]

See below settings of the "Insert Action"

[image]

Below settings of the "Update Action"

[image]

2.) I have also tried by creating a "Process" that is binded to the "Create" button when clicked but it did not worked.

I am open to all suggestions and thank you in advance!

Comment: For something like this, use a stored procedure to accept the field values from APEX instead of having APEX issue an insert. The stored procedure would calculate all of the appropriate column values and issue a single insert with everything in one transaction.

Comment: @pmdba Where can I select the option in APEX that I will use the stored procedure once I click the "Create" button? I don't see this option.

Comment: Create a **process** whose *condition* is set to "When button pressed = CREATE".

Comment: @Littlefoot as you can see from my post that is the second thing I tried doing without success.

Comment: I was answering to your question which says "... that I will use the stored procedure" >>> well, you'd call it in a process (as I said) and pass page items as its parameters.

Comment: @Littlefoot I tried creating the process both in the "after submit" option and also in the "Processing" option.

Comment: @Littlefoot oh ok sorry. I went ahead and created a process. What should I select as type in the "Idetification" section and the "Server side condition"? Also I dont see where to pass page items as parameters. I am very new at using APEX as you can see.

Comment: Easiest way is to create a computation before submit to calculate the value of the column and let the automatic page process take care of the insert. No need to insert and update.

Comment: @KoenLostrie when I create computation it does not let me select "before submit". The options I get are: "New session", "Before header", "After header", "Before regions", "After regions", "Before footer", "After footer", "After submit".

Comment: Apologies it should be after submit. Just make sure it is executed before the process that updates the table

Comment: @KoenLostrie I tried with computation and set the computation to after submit as you suggested but no luck my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I created a workspace on apex.oracle.com to illustrate my answer:

workspace: SO_HELP, username: so_68399404, pwd: so_68399404

App 22384 (Demonstration - EMP / DEPT) is an app generated on the standard emp/dept sample dataset. In the report "Employees", there is a "create" button but employees can also be edited with the edit icon. Both the "create" button and the "edit" link point to the same form (page 4). The salary is depends on the job. If the job is MANAGER then salary is set to 5000 else salary is increased by 1. Similar to your requirement. I did this with an *after submit* computation with code

```
CASE WHEN :P4_JOB = 'MANAGER' THEN 5000 ELSE :P4_SAL + 1 END
```

No other code needed. No dynamic actions, no custom processes. All updates are handled by the process of type "Automatic Row Processing - DML". Login with the credentials above and have a look. If it is not what you need, please explain *exactly* what is different in this app - or create a new form/report on that data to illustrate your issue.

May I suggest you ask your questions this way ? Extract your problem out of your code and illustrate it with the sample dataset. No one knows your actual data, everyone knows the emp/dept schema. That can avoid endless discussions in the comments.

Comment: This might be helpful. Let me try it out and get back to you.

Comment: it not simple to extract my problem and illustrate with the sample dataset you have kindly given me access to. Please understand I cannot show all information about what database tables the page is using because of security reasons. I added 2 more pictures to the main post so you have more details and that can possibly help out. I notice that your object "Employee" on page 4 is of type "Form" however in my case the object  I have is of type "Static Content"

Comment: I have to say that your example in your app is conceptually the same problem that I am facing however the structure that my example is using is different from yours. For example your app is using a "Form" object and I am using a "Static Content" object.

Comment: As I said, please create a page in this app that exactly illustrates your problem - no security limitations here and we both have access.

Comment: Please see page 9 of your app. It shows how the object  'test' is set in my app.

Comment: There is no code in that page to save the data in emp.I tried providing you with an environment so I can help you solve your problem.  Please take time to explain in detail what the behaviour is you are expecting - that code you put in page 9 doesn't do anything... I updated user so_68399404 so he can now access the app - mistake from my part.